# Number Lock light remains on after shutting down computer

Tags: keyboard, shutdown

If the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key active light is lit, on closing down the PC using the top bar menu option `Shut Down...`the light on the keyboard remains lit.

If the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key is depressed before closing down (the light extinguishes) and then closed down, all is well with the world.

The keyboard is a pretty much standard (if ancient) Logitech Internet Pro Keyboard which has worked fine on prior owned PC's running Windoze XP.

The PC is totally dedicated to Ubuntu and was installed from scratch on first use fairly recently.

No lights remain on the PC after close down. There is a not easily accessible switch underneath the machine which removes all power from the PSU.

The system specs:

Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
3.7 GB RAM
Intel Celeron (R) 847 @ 1.1 GHz x 2
Intel Sandybridge Mobile
730+GB HDD

[image]

It's no big deal, but just curious as to why this might be the case.

Comment: Very interesting question! Does it do the same with other keyboards? And what about a rear usb rather than front one, or vice versa?

Comment: I would guess that this is some odd hardware issue - it's be belief that when the computer is shutdown, all systems are powered off including the USB subsystem.  In your case, I am obviously mistaken!

Comment: @Tim I'll need to find another QWERTY keyboard for that (must have on buried in the garage somewhere). Only AZERTY ones available in the shops here (France). I'll try it and let you know. The keyboard is in a rear usb.

Comment: @Tim Just checked (memory cells starting to fade with age!) It's actually a PS2 keyboard and matched to the Lilac coloured socket. It's the mouse which is USB

Comment: Good Golly Miss Molly... those links are from 2006! Perhaps it's time to invest in a new usb keyboard (when next in UK) but a good call Tim, thanks. Seems to explain the issue well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This CNET website](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-7590_102-171778/help-usb-ps2-optical-mouse-keep-light-on-after-pc-shutdown/) says that PS2 outputs can be wired that they are always on.

> Not a bug. Just how some machines are wired.

Maybe time for a USB keyboard ;-)